# Fastest way to compare polygon geometry types

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have two tables which has polygon geometry stored in them. I would like to fetch the polygons present in one table and not present in another table.. As of now I am doing a left outer join and using STAsText() but it is taking lot of time.. FYI,We have 120 million polygons in both the tables. Is there a fast way of fetching? (may be using the spatial indexing, I am not aware of this).

FYI, I am using SQL Server 2012

Comment: There are no indexes on this table.
This is the command I am using for comparision.

select newPolygon.* from 
 table1 newPolygon left join 
 table2 oldPolygon on
 newPolygon.Shape.STAsText() = oldPolygon.Shape.STAsText()
where oldPolygon.Shape is  null

Comment: You should have an index if you are trying to improve response time. Is it possible to create the index, then fire your select query then drop the index?

Comment: This form of `LEFT OUTER JOIN` checking is the way I check for values in one table that are not in another, as I have found it to be faster than using `EXCEPT` or `NOT IN ()` and other alternatives. I'm not very familiar with the Geography data type, so I'm not sure how much spatial indexes will help; they should make some improvement however. Try to remove any NULL values before indexing if you do, as I seem to remember there is a performance issue with NULLs in spatial indexes.

Comment: If you have repeats in 120 Million Rows, you'd probably be better of creating a table of unique polygons with an ID. Then store the PolygonID instead of the Polgyon data in your two tables and compare the PolgyonID. I would imagine comparing an INT column would be a lot faster than comparing polygons.

Answer (score 6):

This should do:

```
select a.*
from dbo.newPolygon as a
left join dbo.OldPolygon as b
   on a.Shape.STEquals(b.Shape) = 1
where b.ID is null
```

If you have a spatial index on the Shape column in both tables, it should support this query. From the documentation:

> Spatial indexes support the following set-oriented geometry methods under certain conditions: STContains(), STDistance(), **STEquals()**, STIntersects(), STOverlaps(), STTouches(), and STWithin(). To be supported by a spatial index, these methods must be used within the WHERE or JOIN ON clause of a query, and they must occur within a predicate of the following general form:
>
> *geometry1. method_name( geometry2) comparison_operator valid_number*

(emphasis mine) Since we are, in fact, using STEquals() in the manner specified that the documentation says, we should be good to go.