# C# SQL Geometry Error: Invalid operator for data type. Operator equals equal to, type equals geometry

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, geospatial

Using C# and LOCAL SQL SERVER
Making an SQL call which is:

```
string cmd2 = "SELECT Circle_ID FROM Circle WHERE Center_Point = geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(";
        cmd2 += center_lat;
        cmd2 += " ";
        cmd2 += center_lng;
        cmd2 += ")',0)";
```

and I receive the error:

> Invalid operator for data type. Operator equals equal to, type equals geometry. Error Number:403,State:1,Class:16

Syntax I believe is correct referencing [#Ref1](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2008/convert-latitude-longitude-to-geography-point.aspx) and [#Ref2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280487.aspx).

Note: I understand about parameterized sql queries which I will be doing. But first I just want to get the sql working.
Thanks

Comment: did u tried `'` instead of `"`

Comment: `string cmd2 = "SELECT Circle_ID FROM Circle WHERE Center_Point = geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT('";
        cmd2 += center_lat;
        cmd2 += " ' ' ";
        cmd2 += center_lng;
        cmd2 += "')',0)";`

Comment: I have and I just get a syntax error `Incorrect syntax near '44.59047'` that's the Center_lat value. I have formatted other strings in the same manner as in the question for inserting the data to sql db.

Comment: is center_lat and center_lng is number?

Comment: then you should convert that

Comment: `string cmd2 = "SELECT Circle_ID FROM Circle WHERE Center_Point = geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT('"; cmd2 += "convert(varchar(20),"+center_lat+")"; cmd2 += " ' ' "; cmd2 += "convert(varchar(20),"+center_lng+")"; cmd2 += "')',0)";`

Comment: Still no avail.. same error as in question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data type allows for certain operations and is not as standard.

the solution I found was:

```
 string cmd2 = "SELECT Circle_ID FROM Circle WHERE Center_Point.STEquals(geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(";
        cmd2 += center_lat;
        cmd2 += " ";
        cmd2 += center_lng;
        cmd2 += ")',0)) = 1;"; // 1 = TRUE
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28986816/fastest-way-to-compare-polygon-geometry-types) post helped me out.

Hope this helps others in the future.